# SML '97: what is exactly the standard syntax?

Tags: standards, sml

I came to this question, when I wanted to check something about the syntax of functor declarations. I came to two contradictory syntax definitions, while the syntax of Standard ML '97, as its name suggest, is supposed to be part of a standard, defined in “The definition of Standard ML — Revised”.

### From the book

[“The definition of Standard ML — Revised”, by R. Milner, page 14, on Google Books](http://books.google.fr/books?id=e0PhKfbj-p8C&lpg=PA11&hl=fr&pg=PA14#v=onepage&q&f=false) says:

```
fundec ::= functor funbinf
funbind ::= funid (strid : sigexp) = strexp <and funbind>
```

I read it as “A functor gets exactly one argument and cannot be said to match a signature”.

### From another reliable source

[“Standard ML syntax summary”, by L. Paulson, page 2, on PDF](http://www.classes.cs.uchicago.edu/archive/2006/fall/15300-1/handouts/ML-syntax.pdf) says (schema approximately re‑expressed using the same notation as in the definition of SML '97):

```
FunctorDeclaration ::= functor FunctorBinding <and FunctorBinding>
FunctorBinding ::= Ident ( FunctorArguments ) : Signature = Structure
FunctorArguments ::= Ident : Signature | Specification
```

I read it as “A functor may get multiple arguments and may be said to match a signature”.

### Question

The two documents says different things, so I'm confused. What is the real definition of Standard ML '97? Or am I just miss‑reading the standard definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapters 2 and 3 of the Definition only give the bare syntax of the language.  That's extended by the "derived forms" (i.e., syntactic sugar) defined in Appendix A, which include the `funid (spec)` form (which is short for `funid (X : sig spec end)` with `X` being opened on the RHS).

See [here](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml.html) for a complete SML grammar including all derived forms.

Comment: OK, thanks. I did not suspected there was derived forms for functors too.

Comment: Yes, probably because, curiously, Appendix B contains the "full grammar" of the core language, but the book does not include one for modules.